# Maximize a 3 variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Let $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+2xz-y^2}-x-z,$$
where $$x+y+z\leq 1, \quad x+y\geq 0.7, \quad x\geq 0, \quad y\geq 0, \quad \text{and} \quad z\geq 0.$$

How could I go about maximizing this function? I cannot use Lagrange multipliers since my constraints are inequalities. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can, in fact, still use Lagrange multipliers with inequality constraints. Look into the concept of a "slack variable". Some sources are

https://machinelearningmastery.com/lagrange-multiplier-approach-with-inequality-constraints/

and 

https://users.wpi.edu/~pwdavis/Courses/MA1024B10/1024_Lagrange_multipliers.pdf

Comment: Break up into sub-cases, depending on which equaliries are satisfied. For each equality, you can use a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the KKT conditions as they generalise the concept of Lagrange multipliers to inequality constraints. If you're just interested in the answer though, your function attains a maximum value of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{7}{10}$ when $(x,y,z)=(\frac{7}{10}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}},0)$